# Show date from database on Picker materialize

Tags: materialize, picker

I have the following code, when I click on the Picker I want to see the date 01/01/2018 selected in the calendar.
    I need the calendar to select the date that contains the value of the imput.

```
   $var_date = '01/01/2018';


<input type="text" name="date" name="date" class="datepicker" value="<?php echo $var_date; ?>">
      <label for="first_name">Date</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the help of `instance.setDate(new Date())`.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var elems = document.querySelector('.datepicker');
        var instance = M.Datepicker.init(elems);
        // instance.open(); This will open your datepicker on its own when page is loaded completely
        instance.setDate(new Date(2018, 2, 8));
    });
</script>
```

**Note-** `new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);`

The argument `monthIndex` is 0-based. This means that `January = 0` and `December = 11`

[MDN - Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

[Materialize - Pickers](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html)

Comment: if you select the date because the month of April is selected?